# Упорядывачение данных

Tags: javascript, node.js, инспекция-кода

Есть исходный массив:

```
[ 'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-1.png',         
  'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-2.png',         
  'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-3.png',         
  'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-4.png',         
  'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-5.png',         
  'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-1.png',        
  'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-2.png',        
  'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-3.png',        
  'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-4.png',        
  'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/s19908f1255e3d10,
  'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/shutterstock_106,
  'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/tel.jpg',       
  'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/unnamed.png' ]
```

Необходимо на его основе сделать массив объектов, который выглядит так:

```
[ { data:                                                                
     [ 'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-1.png',                              
       'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-2.png',                              
       'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-3.png',                              
       'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-4.png',                              
       'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-5.png' ],                            
    fileName: 'coctail',                                                 
    destPath: 'app/img/' },                                              
  { data:                                                                
     [ 'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-1.png',                             
       'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-2.png',                             
       'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-3.png',                             
       'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-4.png' ],                           
    fileName: 'social',                                                  
    destPath: 'app/img/' },                                              
  { data:                                                                
     [ 'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/s19908f1255e3d106eca5d.jpg',         
       'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/shutterstock_106748483-247x180.jpg', 
       'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/tel.jpg',                            
       'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/unnamed.png' ],                      
    fileName: 'testSprite1',                                             
    destPath: 'app/img/' } ]
```

В принципе задача решена, но тот код, который я написал мне самому не очень нравиться. Получилось много циклов и как-то громоздко.
Может кто посмотрит и укажет, где можно было сделать более компактно?

```js
var fileNames = new Set();
var files = [];
var destination = new Set();
//console.log(matches)
matches.forEach((item, i, arr) => {
  if (item.includes(config.spritesFolder)) {
    var pos = item.indexOf(config.spritesFolder);
    var start = item.indexOf('/', pos) + 1;
    var end = item.indexOf('/', start);
    fileNames.add(item.slice(start, end));
    destination.add(item.slice(0, pos));
  }
});
var i = 0;
fileNames.forEach((item, it, arr) => {
  files[i] = {};
  files[i].data = [];
  files[i].fileName = item;
  for (var j = 0; j < matches.length; j++) {
    if (matches[j].indexOf(item) != -1) {
      files[i].data.push(matches[j]);
    }
  }
  i++;
});
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  files[i].destPath = '';
  destination.forEach((item, it, arr) => {
    if (files[i].data[0].indexOf(item) != -1) {
      files[i].destPath = item.replace(config.path.src.dir, config.path.build.dir);
    }
  });
}
console.dir(files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного поразмышляв переписал код следующим образом:

```js
var matches = ['dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-1.png',
  'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-2.png',
  'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-3.png',
  'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-4.png',
  'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-5.png',
  'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-1.png',
  'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-2.png',
  'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-3.png',
  'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-4.png',
  'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/s19908f1255e3d106eca5d.jpg',
  'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/shutterstock_106748483-247x180.jpg',
  'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/tel.jpg',
  'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/unnamed.png'
]

var files = [];

function createItem(arr, i, prop, item) {
  arr[i] = {};
  arr[i][prop] = [];
  arr[i][prop].push(item)
  if (!arr[i].fileName && !arr[i].destPath) {
    var pos = item.indexOf('sprites');
    var start = item.indexOf('/', pos) + 1;
    var end = item.indexOf('/', start);
    arr[i].fileName = item.slice(start, end);
    arr[i].destPath = item.slice(0, pos).replace('dev', 'app');
  }
}
var j = 0;
matches.forEach((item, i, arr) => {
  var pos = item.lastIndexOf('/');
  if (files.length == 0) {
    createItem(files, j, 'data', item);
  } else if (files[j].data[files[j].data.length - 1].includes(item.slice(0, pos))) {
    files[j].data.push(item);
  } else {
    j++;
    createItem(files, j, 'data', item);
  }
});
console.log(files);
```

Я решил создавать объекты в массве files прямо в цикле по matches и использовать дополнительную функцию для создания необходимых свойств этих объектов.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arr = ['dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-1.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-2.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-3.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-4.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/coctail/coc-5.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-1.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-2.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-3.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/social/advan-4.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/s19908f1255e3d10',
    'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/shutterstock_106',
    'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/tel.jpg',
    'dev/img/sprites/testSprite1/unnamed.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/testSprite2/unnamed.png',
    'dev/img/sprites/testSprite3/unnamed.png'],
i = newArrLength = 0,
newArr = [],
tempArr2 = tempArr = [],
createData = function (file, path) {
    this.data = tempArr;
    this.filename = file;
    this.path = path;
};
while (i < arr.length) {
    var splited1 = arr[i].split('/');
    splited2 = arr[i + 1] ? arr[i + 1].split('/') : false;
    if (splited1[3] === splited2[3]) {
        tempArr[tempArr.length] = arr[i];
    } else {
        tempArr[tempArr.length] = arr[i];
        tempArr2 = new createData(splited1[3], splited1[0] + '/' + splited1[1]);
        newArr[newArr.length] = tempArr2;
        tempArr = tempArr2 = [];
    };
    ++i;
}

console.log(newArr[0]);
```

Comment: да, код далеко не самый красивый, но достаточно компактный, мог написать более сжато, но так нагляднее

Comment: почему заминусовали ответ? неплохо было бы и причины описать...

Comment: возможно, это были ф̶а̶н̶а̶т̶и̶к̶и̶  любители "красивого кода".... Поверьте, я встречал таких людей)